# SharePoint 2013 Task Sync with Exchange 2013 CAS Cluster

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server, sharepoint-2013

We have a question regarding SharePoint task synch with Exchange (CAS with NLB - CAS cluster).

NLB - Round-Robin DNS.

In MySites task list user can select "Sync to Outlook". We found this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649094%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx but it doesn't say on which servers do we have to run this ps1 script if we have a CAS Cluster (2 CAS, 4MBX).

We think that we have to run this script on both CAS servers.

Another question: Which URL will be used for synchronization when user selects to synch tasks? I couldn't find any information on this.

Thank you for all the help.

Ales

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just to let you that we executed that script on CAS server. And also one more thing -> article for Task Sync (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554516.aspx) is missing one important information. EWSManagedAPI.msi must be installed on all WFE and APP servers